# What does the variable hold if there is no match after running a LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, webmethod

```
[WebMethod]
public List<FavoritesTO> getFavorites(string username)
{
    using (FavoritesDataContext db = new FavoritesDataContext ())
    {
        var query = from row in db.Favorites
                    where username == row.username
                    select row.imdbId;
        // here
    }
}
```

In the area marked as here, what will the query variable hold, say in case there is no username in my table which matches with the username passed to the function?

Comment: The question doesn't match the code. You did not run the query! Making a query does not run it, it just makes a query object. A query is a question, not the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value of `query` will just be the query - until you try to evaluate the results, nothing knows whether or not there are any. After that, I suspect that LINQ to SQL will cache the results - but it's still *conceptually* just a query.

If you're asking whether it's `null` or not, no - it's just an empty sequence. So `query.Count()` would return 0, `query.Any()` would return `false` etc.

Answer (score 0):

An emtpy `IEnumerable<Favorites>`.

Comment: Technically no. The query is still an `IQueryable<Favorites>`. It has not been converted to an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: AKA what Jon Skeet said :P

Comment: Even more technically it will be WhereSelectIterator or something similar, correct :) But not sure for LINQ to SQL.

Comment: `IQueryable<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`, so this answer is correct as it stands.  I think it's more helpful (to users less familiar with Linq) to describe the output as an empty `IEnumerable<T>`.